# How to use global variables in event handlers

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a global variable contacts,
  *var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();*

I have an KeyUphandler for my textbox called search().

In search(),
    contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail() gives out an error, "**Cant call method getPrimaryEmail of undefined**"

However contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail() works fine in other normal functions.

Cant we use global variables in event handlers?

The code is given below,

//CODE starts

```
   var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();

function ShowAuto() {

    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Simple Autocomplete');

    var Panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel').setWidth('555px');

    var textBox = app.createTextBox().setName('textBox').setWidth('330px').setId('textBox');

    var tBoxHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('search');
    tBoxHandler.addCallbackElement(textBox);
    textBox.addKeyUpHandler(tBoxHandler);

    var listBox =    app.createListBox().setName('list').setWidth("330px").setId('list').setVisibleItemCount(5)
               .setStyleAttribute("border", "1px solid white")
               .setStyleAttribute("background", "white").setVisible(false);

   Panel.add(app.createLabel().setId('label'));



   Panel.add(textBox);
   Panel.add(listBox);

   app.add(Panel);


   var ownerEmail  = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();


   // I used this method first.. It din work.
   // var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
   // for (var i in contacts) 
   // {
   //  var emailStr = contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail();
   //  conts[i]=emailStr;
   // Browser.msgBox(emailStr);
   // }

   //These two calls are just to test, the contacts Array, They work fine :)

   getContact(0);
   getContact(1);

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   ss.show(app);


   }

   function getContact(n)
   {

    // Browser.msgBox(contacts[n].getPrimaryEmail());
     Logger.log(contacts[n].getPrimaryEmail());  //works  fine 
     return contacts[n].getPrimaryEmail();
   }


   function search(e)
   {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   //Logger.log(contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail()); //Not working

     app.getElementById('label').setText(e.parameter.textBox.toString());
    // app.getElementById('label').setText(conts[0]);
     app.getElementById('list').setVisible(true);

     var searchKey = new RegExp(e.parameter.textBox.toString(),"gi");
     if (searchKey == "") 
       app.getElementById('textBox').setValue('');


     var listBoxCount = 0;

     for (i=0;i<5;i++){

       //Here is where i get error
        if(contacts[i].indexOf(e.parameter.textBox)!=-1 && listBoxCount < 5)
        {
          app.getElementById('list').addItem(conts[i]);
          listBoxCount++;
        }
     }

     }
```

Sorry if i was unclear

Comment: Need eventandler code at least and is it defined in the same scope as contacts.

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of contacts[0] in the main UI function ?

Comment: This is supposed to work (although I would not recommend such usage). Please post a minimal but complete code example where you can reproduce the problem. Tip: you can edit your question to include additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I have used [`UserProperties.setProperty`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties#setProperty(String,String)) and `getProperty` function to avoid the use of global variables.

Whenever a server handler is invoked, the global variables will be recalculated as given in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_serverhandler,  so mine was not working properly.

Thanks for the support guys :)